# Java Prompt for Folder

Tags: java, directory, text-files, search-engine, prompt

I have to create an internal search engine for a company. The clients will have a folder which contains multiple text files. Right now my code works fine if I include the program in the same folder as the text files. Is there anyway for me to be able to prompt a user so they could give me the name of the file and then use that to search through the contents of the text files in that folder? Below is what I have so far. Thanks for the help!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Boolean;

public class SearchFunction{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        try{
            /*create a count for each text file and a variable 
             *for the textfiles. */
            int count = 1;

            /* Wrap the File as a boolean so it can run in the loop*/

            //boolean boolFileName = Boolean.parseBoolean(fileName);
            do {

                /*read the file and search for the keyword/phrase
                 *Loop through all the text files. */

                String fileName = "Buyerbuyerserver" + count + "Log.txt";

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (fileName));

                int linecount = 0;
                    String line;
                System.out.println("Searching for '" + args[0] + "' in file " + fileName);

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    linecount++;
                    int indexfound = line.indexOf(args[0]);

                    if (indexfound > -1){
                        System.out.println("Word was found at positon " + indexfound + " on line " + linecount);
                    }
                }
                br.close();
                count++;
            } while (count > 0);    
        } 
        /*Catch if the file is not found*/
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: If you want the user to enter the file name, you might want to add a ui to your program...you can use swings to achieve this

Comment: @rahulpasricha May I ask how swing can help this issue?

Comment: just an idea, if you need a front end which makes it easier for the user to search a file name.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, then I hope this could help you:

1)import java.io.* at the beginning of your code as below:

```
import java.io.*;
```

2) Prompt the user for the file name:

```
System.out.println("Please Specify The File With Its Path: ");
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String filename=s.nextLine();
```

3) Proceed with your own code after previous 2 steps